# css are not aplying

Tags: javascript, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Z3W.png)

I try to change button color via applying styles.css to button component. Component button got className for switching from reducer. After done condition in reducer className in button component got its correct value, but color not switch.... any ideas why?

please see 
"
**button  key={id} className ={props.optionStyle}**
"

reduser.js

```js
....
 if (newOption.option === answer) {

                return {
                    ...state,
                    userAnswer: newOption.option,
                    answer: answer,
                    answerTrue: true,
                    currentSrc: currentSrcT,
                    questAudio: false,
                    optionStyle: "styles.correct"

                };
                
                ......
```

component with button

```css
import React from 'react';
import styles from './item.css';

const OptionItem = (props) => {
 const { option, image, id} = props.optionAnswer ;
 const { onChoiseOption} = props ;

 const  onButtonChose = (id) =>{
 if(props.answerTrue) {

    }
}


const onChoiseOptionComp = e => {
onChoiseOption(),
    onButtonChose(id)
}

return (
    <div>
        <button  key={id} className={props.optionStyle}
                onClick={
                    onChoiseOptionComp
                }
        >
            {option}
            <p ><img src={image} alt="cartinka" className={styles.imageOption}/></p>

        </button>
    </div>

    )
};
```

item.css

```css
.imageOption {
    width: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.optionChose {
    background-color: blue;
}

.correct {
    background-color: crimson;
}

.nonCorrect {
    background-color: #2ddc66;
}
```

.....if I tried to change className manually - that work fine

Comment: is the `debugger;` line part of your actual code? Can you please format it in a readable way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use CSS modules in runtime code, and this won't work because it gets resolved before the code is built/ran.

`optionStyle: "correct"` in reducer looks more reasonable.

Secondly, your reducer gives you a string value "styles.correct" that is not the same as the variable `styles.correct`. This is one way to fix it:

```
className={ props.optionStyle === "correct" ? styles.correct : styles.nonCorrect }
```

Comment: tell me please how it fix?

Comment: @VladaRasputina change `optionStyle: "styles.correct"` to `optionStyle: "correct"` in your reducer.

Comment: if i write it manualy in conponent like className={styles.correct} - it works but value from props (reducer) dont work

Comment: `styles.correct` is not the same as the string `"styles.correct"`, which you are passing from you reducer.

Comment: Try this instead: `className = {{ props.optionStyle === "styles.correct" ? styles.correct : styles.nonCorrect }}`. Of course it is ugly, but just to test if that is the problem.

Comment: but if i wrote without "" i have error like " Uncaught ReferenceError: styles is not defined"

Comment: Try single curly braces like in my answer, I made a typo in the comment.

Comment: it works, but now i have 'styles.nonCorrect'' in default but i need '''undefined'' for colorless button :)

Comment: @VladaRasputina then `className={ props.optionStyle === "correct" ? styles.correct : undefined }`. It reads "If I see that optionStyle is "correct" in props, then use the styles.correct from CSS modules, otherwise don't".

Comment: ...assuming that you rename the string to just "correct" in the reducer, which you should do.

Comment: className={ props.optionStyle === "correct" ? styles.correct ? styles.nonCorrect : undefined } - i need second styles also, but how it write in short (if - else if - else)

Comment: @VladaRasputina You cannot use the ternary operator like that. The best way is to write a function that takes a string such as "correct" as input and returns the class you want, then do `className={this.myfunction(props.optionStyle)}`

Comment: This is a different question, though. It would be better to open a new question. I assume the original problem to be fixed.